# How to make subscript/superscript mutually exclusive in CKEDITOR?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using CKEDITOR 4 for accept formatted text (more specifically: a chemical formula). Users can format parts of their formula with subscript or superscript, but they should never be allowed to select both at the same time. Unfortunately, CKEDITOR does allow text to be both subscript and superscript at the same time. How can I modify the behavior of CKEDITOR to unselect subscript if the user clicks on superscript (or vice versa)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it turns out it wasn't that hard after all.. After playing around a bit, I finally ended up with this (working) code:

```
editor.on('beforeCommandExec', function (event) {
    if (event.data.name == 'superscript' && event.editor.commands.subscript.state == 1)
        editor.execCommand('subscript');
    else if (event.data.name == 'subscript' && event.editor.commands.superscript.state == 1)
        editor.execCommand('superscript');
});
```